# Strings.TrimとStrings.Trim$その他「$」ありなしで動作は異なりますか

Tags: .net, vb.net

以下2つのTrimとTrim$や、MidとMid$等「$」のあるメソッドと「$」がないメソッドがありますが、動作は異なるのでしょうか。
私としては、それぞれのメソッドにカーソルを当てると、どちらも「Function Trim(str As String) As String」と表示されるので、実は同じメソッドが呼ばれているのではないかと思っています。

```
   Sub Main()
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Trim(" abc ")
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Trim$(" abc ")
   End Sub
```

※VB（6.0）やVBAではなく、Visual Basic（.NET）の場合です。
※ターゲットフレームワークは4.7.2。OSはWindows 10です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下の記事が該当すると思われます。
最後の **非$関数は、$関数とまったく同じように機能します。これは、古いコードとの下位互換性のためにのみ保持されています。** が当てはまるのでしょう。

[what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8341524/9014308)
問：

> what is the meaning of the dollar sign after a method name in vb.net
> vb.netのメソッド名の後のドル記号の意味は何ですか。
> like this:
>
> ```
> Replace$("EG000000", "0", "")
> ```

短い答え：

> Old type notifier - [see this](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html)
> 古い型文字です
> Some other old ones:
>
> ```
> & -> Long
> % -> Integer
> # -> Double
> ! -> Single
> @ -> Decimal
> $ -> String
> ```
>
> Still exist in VB.Net for the sake of backward compatibility...
> 下位互換性のためにVB.Netにはまだ存在しています。
>
> COMMENT: For the sake of completeness, the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
> 完全を期すために

長い答え:

> In "classic" VB, there were two versions of the built in-string functions. Let me use Left as an example:
> 「クラシック」VBには、組み込みの文字列関数の2つのバージョンがありました。 例としてLeftを使用してみましょう：
>
> - Left(s, length) takes a variant as the first parameter and returns a variant.
> - Left$(s, length) takes a string as the first parameter and returns a string.
>
> This distinction still exists in modern-day VBA.
> この違いは、現在のVBAにも存在しています。
>
> I suspect that the reason behind this is that strings in VBA cannot be `Null` (note that `Null <> ""`). Thus, when dealing with nullable database fields, you had to use variant variables. Variant variables can take any value, including all of the integral values (strings, integers, ...) as well as some special values such as `Null`, `Empty` or `Missing`. The non-$ functions allowed you to use variants as input and get variants as output. For example, `Left(Null, ...)` returns `Null`.
> これの背後にある理由は、VBA内の文字列を`Null`にすることはできないためだと思います（`Null <> ""` に注意してください）。したがって、null許容データベースフィールドを処理するときは、バリアント変数を使用する必要がありました。バリアント変数は、すべての整数値（文字列、整数など）や、 `Null`、 `Empty`、 `Missing`などの特別な値を含む任意の値を取ることができます。非$関数を使用すると、バリアントを入力として使用し、バリアントを出力として取得できます。 たとえば、 `Left（Null、...）`は `Null`を返します。
>
> In VB.NET, this distinction is no longer necessary: The non-$ functions do exactly the same as the $ functions, which are kept only for backwards compatibility with old code.
> VB.NETでは、この区別は不要になりました。非$関数は、$関数とまったく同じように機能します。これは、古いコードとの下位互換性のためにのみ保持されています。